# Im encountering a name error with this program involving if/elif/else commands since Im starting coding in IST next year at school

Tags: nameerror

```
rain = input('Is it currently raining? ')
if rain == 'Yes':
print('You should take the bus.')
elif rain == 'No':
d = int(input('How far in km do you need to travel? '))
if d >= 2:
print("You should ride your bike.")
else:
print("You should walk.")
```

name of error that appears: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 6, in 
    if d >= 2:
NameError: name 'd' is not defined

Comment: Can you [edit] this question to reflect the indentation used in your code? It's unclear whether the `if` statements are nested and indentation is very important to python syntax

Comment: my codes are all nested in the same columns and rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your error message your code probably looks like this:

```py
rain = input('Is it currently raining? ')
if rain == 'Yes':
    print('You should take the bus.')
elif rain == 'No':
    d = int(input('How far in km do you need to travel? '))
if d >= 2: # error happens on this line because 'd' is only defined if you answer 'No' to the first question
    print("You should ride your bike.")
else:
    print("You should walk.")
```

This will work without throwing that error:

```py
rain = input('Is it currently raining? ')
if rain == 'Yes':
    print('You should take the bus.')
elif rain == 'No':
    # do all of this code if rain == 'No'
    d = int(input('How far in km do you need to travel? '))
    if d >= 2:
        print("You should ride your bike.")
    else:
        print("You should walk.")
```